# Get image from JButton and export to PDF

Tags: java, image, pdf, netbeans, itext

How can I upload an image by `JButton` and export that image to a PDF file using Java Netbeans?

I am using the `iText` library but I didn't get results yet,

Thanks

Comment: mmmm, where is your code then?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "upload an image by JButton" ? You want to be able to select an image from a file choser and then to export the selected image as a pdf ? If yes, then read:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

then for the PDF exportation, you have to create a PDF with the image in it. Converting an image to pdf with something like iText costs, meanwhile, if just having the image into the pdf does the work for you, then something like that should it:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/test.pdf"));
document.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("/logo.png"));
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

Hope I helped, and have a nice day.

Comment: yeah exactly i wnt to select an image by a file chooser and export it to a PDF report

Comment: Then that should be enough, read the doc's on jfilechooser, then everything should be good all right. Don't forget to read about outputstreams and inputstreams if you've never done that before